# Block Matching optimization using x86/x64 Streaming SIMD Extension

Tags: c++, c, optimization, sse, simd

This is going to be the very first SO Question I'm posting!

```
    std::cout << "Hello mighty StackOverflow!" << std::endl;
```

I'm trying to optimize a "Block Matching" implementation for stereo-vision application using Intel's SSE4.2 and/or AVX intrinsics. I'm using "Sum of Absolute Differences" to find the best matching block. In my case `blockSize` will be an **odd** number, such as 3 or 5. This a snippet of my C++ code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            minS = INT_MAX;
            for (int k = 0; k <= beta; ++k) {
                S = 0;
                for (int l = i; l < i + blockSize; ++l) {
                    for (int m = j; m <= j + blockSize ; ++m) {
                        // adiff(a,b) === abs(a-b)
                        S += adiff(rImage.at<uchar>(l, m), lImage.at<uchar>(l, m + k));
                    }
                }
                if (S < minS) {
                    minS = S;
                    kStar = k;
                }
            }
            disparity.at<uchar>(i, j) = kStar;
        }
    }
```

I know that the Streaming SIMD Extension contain many instructions to facilitate block-matching using SAD such as `_mm_mpsadbw_epu8` and  `_mm_sad_epu8` , but they all seam to be targeting `blockSize`s that are 4, 16 or 32. [e.g. this code from Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/motion-estimation-with-intel-streaming-simd-extensions-4-intel-sse4#F.%20Intelr%20SSE4%20-%20Optimized%20Function%20for%2016x16%20Blocks). My problem is that in my application `blockSize` is an odd number, mostly 3 or 5.

I have considered the following starting point:

```
            r0 = _mm_lddqu_si128 ((__m128i*)&rImage.at<uchar>(i, j));
            l0 = _mm_lddqu_si128 ((__m128i*)&lImage.at<uchar>(i, j));
            s0 = _mm_abs_epi8 (_mm_sub_epi8 (r0 , l0) );
```

but from here, I don't know of a means to sum up 3 or 5 consecutive bytes from `s0`!

I would appreciate any thoughts on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  That's a well-composed question for a new member.  I suspect you'll get a good answer shortly.  :)

Comment: Is it only (horizontal) disparity you are interested in?

Comment: I suspect the best answer will be to simply pad your rows/columns with zeros (so that those entries contribute nothing to your final sum).

Comment: The sum will be over 3x3 or 5x5 blocks -- That's 1+8 and 1+24 entries all together. The 8 and 24 OTOH are figures that could be handled efficiently with SIMD.

Comment: Yes @AkiSuihkonen. I assume a previous leveling has been run on the data.

Comment: @twalberg unfortunately that would not work for the full SSE SAD operations as the SAD needs to be calculated using a window running across `rImage` (the "current" blocks). At least I can't think of a way to do that. The only choice will be to load a 128-bit register in 3 steps and then perform `_mm_subs_epu8` (with loss of precision/data) , `_mm_abs_epi8` and then a somehow add the 9 bytes horizontally, which again there seems no (easy) way to do it.

Comment: Perhaps mask and/or shuffle your inputs with `_mm_and_si128` so you can feed them to `_mm_sad_epu8`, and only have the bytes you want in each qword.  Or with some recent AVX-512 there might be more support for different SAD granularity, I forget.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect if blocksize is as small as 3-5 bytes x 3-5 bytes, you'd get fairly little benefit from using SSE or similar instructions, because you'll spend far too much of the "gain" from doing the math quickly in "swizzling" (moving data from one place to another).

However, looking at the code, it looks like you are processing the same `rImage[i, j]` multiple times, which I think doesn't make sense.

Comment: ... Unless the runtime data cache system can successfully predict which chunks of data should be directly brought ahead of time into the L1 or possibly even L2 cache.  From the looks of the code, the data blocks may be accessed predictably in the loop so the runtime system may be able to eliminate this swizzling overhead and the code may benefit from the SIMD intrinsics.

Comment: Yes, the trouble with swizzling isn't a cache-dependent, but to do with the fact that you need extra instructions to perform the operations to move data around. And I'm pretty sure the rImage(i,j) is in cache after the first loop, but it's still extra instructions to calculate the sum of those bytes again.

Comment: I'm curious where you suspect data is being moved (assuming you mean that the `S += ...` line is causing data to be moved (rather than just read from the cache, possibly into a register - or do you mean that the process of reading data from cache into register is a bottlenecking data "swizzle"?)).

Comment: No, I mean if you try to fit 9 bytes from a 3 x 3 square pixel pattern into a SSE or AVX word, you need to shuffle the bytes into their respective position. To make sensible use of SSE instructions, they need to contain multiple data items that can be done the same operation on. Otherwise it is not "Single Instruction Multiple Data". Sure, you could take 3 bytes at a time, but it's debatable if that's even meaningful.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: An experiment I've done so far with a 3x4 blocks (instead of 3x3) as an approximation showed a <b>30x</b> performance improvement after compiler optimization on GCC and ICC. The reference code was also given some pointer tweaks. I don't see any sizzling being done here either, as accesses are in an overall ascending order and I guess the cache will be comfortably able to handle the few backs and forts there.